# HTC Dream - Upgrade Android OS and driver for 64-bit Windows 7 Home

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, htc-dream, 1.6-donut, usb-drivers

I have just bought an unlocked HTC Dream G1 android cell phone. It has Android 1.5 installed. Can someone guide me as to how to upgrade to Android 2.X series? Also, which android 2.X OS would be the best choice? I have heard Android 2.2 is best for this cell phone compared to Android 2.3 or 3.0.

Also, I have been unable to find drivers for this cell phone to connect my micro-SD memory card in cell phone to my Windows 7 Home 64-bit OS. I believe the problem is because I have a 64-bit OS. Where can I find the drivers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) that come with the android SDK will work for that device. Your best bet is to install a version of CyanogenMod 5 or 6.x. But keep in mind, that device is a dinosaur. It does not run android 2.x well at all, especially compared to the specs of current devices.

I had CyanogemMod 6 on my ADP1 (HTC Dream/G1) and, while it worked, it was extremely slow. Also, the CyanogenMod team no longer even officially supports that device. The "old" CyanogenMod thread on [XDA is here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=722801). I am not sure if it still has download links or not.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I will test it out. I want to upgrade to Android 2.x series, because many apps do not work. Also, its android 1.5 not 1.6. I had made a mistake in the question. So, I cant even use the apps available on https://market.android.com. Do you think, upgrading to a better 1.x would be a good choice? Thanks again.

Comment: You can get a 2.x version to work (CyanogenMod 6.1 i think is 2.2), but as I said, it will probably seem very laggy.